# g++ unordered_map has no at() function?

Tags: c++, gcc, unordered-map

I've been developing using Visual Studio 2010, and then compiling a Linux 64 version on another machine.  To cover the difference between the 2 different compilers/environments, we have conditional include statements:

```
#ifdef __linux__
#include <tr1/unordered_map>
#endif

#ifdef _WIN32
#include <unordered_map>
#endif 
using namespace std;  // covers std::unordered_map
using namespace std::tr1; // covers tr/unordered_map

unordered_map<string,string> map;
```

For `unordered_map`, I've been using this documentation:  [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_map/unordered_map/), which shows an `at()` method to look up a key in the map.  (Unlike the `[]` operator, this won't insert key into the map if not found.)

When I tried to compile the code on the Linux machine, gcc throws an error saying

> test_map.cpp:18: error: 'class std::tr1::unordered_map, std::allocator >, std::basic_string, std::allocator >, std::tr1::hash, std::allocator > >, std::equal_to, std::allocator > >, std::allocator, std::allocator >, std::basic_string, std::allocator > > >, false>' has no member named 'at'

The version of gcc on this machine is:

> g++ (GCC) 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-46)

I tried compiling on a newer install of Linux with version:

> gcc version 4.4.6 20120305 (Red Hat 4.4.6-4) (GCC)

and got the same error.

So my question has 2 parts:

- Is there a work around so I can still use the `unordered_map.at()`
  function?
- Where would I find the API docs for Linux unordered_map so
  I can be aware of any other discrepancies?  (I looked at [GNU online
  docs](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/) but I could figure out where to find the API reference that
  shows class and functions.)

**UPDATE**

I learned a lot from the responses posted here, so thanks to all. [us2012's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19277636/376527) explained how to work around the compile issue, but in the end, I switched to using `boost::unordered_map` as suggested by [John Dibling](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19277648/376527).  (I decided to take everyone's warnings about the *experimental* C++11 support seriously, as well as also not wanting to inadvertently force a compiler setting on clients who are using our library.)  This gave me a clean compile in both Windows and Linux, and no code change was required (other than removing the reference to `std` and `tr1`).  Also I switched to use http://cppreference.com site, which has straightened me out with other problems already as well.  (Surprisingly, this site never came up in any of my Google searches for C++ API docs.)

Thanks again, for everyone's great explanations.

Comment: Can't test it right now, but I *think* in gcc 4.4.6 those features should be accessible via the `std` namespace instead of `tr1`. Try `#include <unordered_map>` and remove `using namespace std::tr1` - and make sure to compile with `-std=c++0x`. Whatever you do, `using namespace` with both `std` and `std::tr1` seems to be asking for trouble.

Comment: Both `tr1` and GCC 4.4 (not to mention 4.1) are kinda prehistoric now. I realize you probably don't have much choice, but you gotta keep in mind the doc applies to the C++11 standard, not necessarily to `tr1`. For the record, GCC 4.4 is from 2009...

Comment: http://gcc.gnu.org/develop.html check release timeline here. that's a really old compiler.

Comment: @syam et al:  GCC 4.4.6 is the version that is part of the RHEL6 distros.  Staying on the version in the distro is reasonable in production environments, if that the company's policy.

Comment: @us2012: that fix worked for GCC 4.4.6 and it compiled cleanly.  So I'll retire the older machine.  You could post your answer and I could accept it.

Comment: @JohnDibling I didn't say it was unreasonable, I just said that any discrepancy between the up-to-date docs and an outdated compiler are to be expected. As a side note, we're using GCC 4.8 in production on Debian systems (latest stable being Wheezy, shipping with GCC 4.7). The worst part is there isn't any package yet for cross-compiling so we made our own, built from source. :p

Comment: @SamGoldberg Glad to hear. And yeah, retiring GCC 4.1 is definitely the right choice if you need *any* C++11, or even just TR1, features.

Comment: @JohnDibling: Yes, we are trying to compile using the distro included on Linux Centos. A quick check with some of our clients who are using our library confirms that they are also using 4.4.x (and also using Linux Centos).  So that's about as updated as we can be for now.

Comment: @SamGoldberg, if you have to stick to GCC 4.4 then you probably shouldn't be trying to use C++11 features, because GCC 4.4 pre-dates the C++11 standard and so the support is only experimental. If this is code you're shipping to clients then don't require them to use `-std=c++0x` to use your code, the C++0x support in GCC 4.4 is unsupported and unmaintained now.

Comment: Totally agree with @JonathanWakely.  Don't try to use C++11 if you stuck with 4.4.  I'm in the same spot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GCC 4.4 already supports these features as part of `-std=c++0x`. There is no need for the `tr1` namespace, and the include can just be `<unordered_map>`.

Either way, don't be too liberal with `using namespace`, especially with namespaces that may have considerable overlap, this becomes a big problem. For more information about the use of namespaces, have a look at [GOTW](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/053.htm).

Comment: Regarding namespaces, I agree. This is something we wrote a while ago (while in the earliest stages of learning c++).  In our our more recent code, we have become much more parsimonious with the `using namespace`.

Comment: Regarding using `std=c++0x` -- I would strongly discourage using this for production work.  It predates the C++11 Standard, and gnu itself says that C++0x support is *experimental* in 4.4.

Answer (score 5):

You're in a pretty sticky spot.

GCC 4.4.6, which is what's in the RHEL6 distro, is pre-C++11.  The TR1 libraries predate C++11, and many of the components that were introduced to C++11 were signifigantly changed from TR1 before Standardization was complete.

`unordered_map` is one of those components.

In the TR1 days, `unordered_map` didn't have an `at()` member function.  This is present in the C++11 spec.

Your VS2010 compiler is using the C++11 spec (at least for `unordered_map`, to a degree), but GCC 4.4.6 has no concept of C++11.  You are compiling against 2 different languages, in effect.

It's all still C++, at least at some level, so there should be an opportunity to find some common ground.  For what it's worth, I don't think that I would personally use anything from TR1 for production work -- but that's me.

As suggested elsewhere, to achieve the same effect you can `find` the key.

The bottom line for you I think is this.  In GCC 4.4, C++0x support (note I don't say C++11) is experimental.  If it were me, I would not use any of the `std=c++0x` functionality for production work.  I would also not use TR1 for production work.

This leaves you three choices:

1. Don't use a hash map at all
2. Use a hash map from Boost, or another reputable 3rd party library
3. Write your own hash map.

Comment: I'm a little confused by your answer - are you saying not use `unordered_map` at all in 4.4.6, or just not use the `at()` method? Also, it did compile using the `-std=c++0x` flag.  Is that also problematic?

Comment: @SamGoldberg:  I've tried to clarify a bit.  I'm saying don't use any C++0x features from GCC 4.4 for production work.  This is just my opinion.

Comment: @SamGoldberg:  Also, for a quick online reference to the C++ language, don't use cplusplus.com.  It's full of misinformation.  Use cppreference.com instead, but by all means, get yourself a copy of the Standard.

Answer (score 2):

> For `unordered_map`, I've been using this documentation: cplusplus.com, which shows an at() method to look up a key in the map.

But you're not using `unordered_map`, you're using `tr1::unordered_map`. That's not the same thing.

The docs you're looking at are for part of the C++11 standard library, which was published in 2011. The GCC release you're using is from 2009.  Unsurprisingly GCC 4.4 doesn't support C++11 properly.  TR1 is **not** the same thing as C++11, the containers in TR1 are early experimental versions, and don't include the `at()` member.

In any case, cplusplus.com is rubbish, you're better off looking at http://cppreference.com

> Is there a work around so I can still use the unordered_map.at() function?

`std::tr1::unordered_map` doesn't have an `at()` member.  You can enable experimental support for C++0x (the "codename" used before C++11 was finished) in GCC 4.4 with the `-std=c++0x` option, allowing you to use GCC's version of `std::unordered_map`, but requiring clients to do the same to use your code is not a great idea.  Stick to portable features that are properly supported in your compiler version.

> Where would I find the API docs for Linux unordered_map so I can be aware of any other discrepancies? (I looked at [GNU online docs](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs) but I could figure out where to find the API reference that shows class and functions.)

Follow a "Standard C++ Library Manual" link, then the "API and Source Documentation" link, then there's a link to the API reference [for the 4.4 release](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/libstdc++-html-USERS-4.4/index.html)

Don't forget to check the right docs, either `std::tr1::unordered_map` or `std::unordered_map`, depending which you're trying to use.

Comment: Question: the clients I checked with are also using GCC 4.4. We are supplying them with a `.lib` and `.so` file (they can use whichever they like). The `unordered_map` is not directly exposed to them (although they can access it if they want to), because it is mainly meant to be an internal data structure on the class.  Can't they compile without the `-std=c++0x` flag if they either: a) don't directly access the map, or b) only access tr1 methods of the map?

Comment: a) Yes, if it's purely internal to your library, and nothing else your library exposes in its interface is [incompatible](http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Cxx11AbiCompatibility). **That means it can't even be mentioned in a header file that clients use** because clients won't even be able to include the file if it uses `std::unordered_map` and they don't use `-std=c++0x`.

Comment: b) That question doesn't make any sense, there aren't "tr1 methods of the map" if it's a completely different type. If you have an object of type `std::unordered_map` then that's its type, you can't "pretend" it's an object of type `std::tr1::unordered_map`. The types have different implementations and different definitions.  That's like saying "access the `std::vector` methods of a `std::string`, it's nonsense.

Comment: As John Dibling suggests, using a hash map from Boost would avoid this whole problem, as it will work with the Microsoft compiler and the GNU compiler, and will work in C++03 code and C++11 code, and (I believe) will provide the `at()` member function.

Answer (score 1):

Equivalent should be:

```
mymap->find(key)->second
```

`find()` gives you an iterator, so you should check that this is not `mymap.end()`.