# Which gcc version is needed to use unordered_map from C++11?

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, unordered-map

I am currently on RHEL 5.4 with gcc 4.1 installed, but I want to use `unordered_map`. As I found out, this is only introduced in C++11 to the standard, and therefore not available. One alternative would be using `__gnu_cxx::hash_map`, but I would prefer using standards.

On another development host I happend to have RHEL 6.4 and gcc 4.4, which knows `unordered_map`, but gives the following warning:

> ../include/c++/4.4.7/c++0x_warning.h:31:2: error: #error This file requires compiler and library support for the upcoming ISO C++ standard, C++0x. This support is currently experimental, and must be enabled with the -std=c++0x or -std=gnu++0x compiler options.

From the gcc [homepage](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html) I can't seem to find out which gcc version supports `unordered_map`.

[edit]
To clarify my question:
I am stuck to several operating systems and their versions by customer requirements, therefore I cannot always update to the latest GCC version and be happy. I need to maintain compatibility of my software across all platforms.

I am therefore searching for the minimum GCC version required to use `unordered_map`. I am aware of the fact that supplying `-std=c++0x` to GCC fixes the error above, but I dont know how far the "experimental" warning means ***I should not be using*** `unordered_map`.

Some guys in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19277122/g-unordered-map-has-no-at-function?rq=1) strongly advise **not to use** this experimental C++11 implementation

... so what should I do?

Comment: Did you actually *read* the error? Especially the bit at the end about compiler options.

Comment: Yes I *did* read the warning, and I am fully aware of the warning going away with the mentioned options. The very natural question however is, what `experimental` means, and if this is of any concern for me if I only want to use `unordered_map` out of C++11.

Comment: There is no excuse for using gcc 4.1 for C++11. Simply get the *most recent* version.

Comment: Its not me to decide what version of gcc shall/can be used on our various platforms (redhat, solaris, hp-ux, aix), its depending on our customers installations and porting/migration efforts. I *know* the most recent would of course be the best choice, but this will not be possible so I'm trying to find out the *minimum* version I need for `unordered_map` (I dont *want* and dont *need* the whole C++11 standard), and I would be very thankful if someone could answer this for me.

Comment: I upvote this question because I'm in similar situation where I'm stuck with a certain old version of gcc and whenever I want to try some C++11 feature, I got this error. "experimental" scares people away. I wish gcc could continuously and incrementally include new language features to -std=gnu++xx when newer -std=c++xx is not completed yet.

Comment: For more recent features, you can use this web page: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support. Unfortunately, it seems for C++11, it wasn't updated properly.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot find such information on the GCC page. There is information about [library features](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html#status.iso.200x), but only about current version of GCC. In your GCC 4.4, you can simply use `-std=c++0x` flag to remove the warning.

If you are scared about experimental and cannot update the compiler - just don't use unordered_map from C++11. You can write your own, use one from `tr1`, or use the one from `boost`, no matter.

If you just look at GCC site - there is message there:

> Important: GCC's support for C++11 is still experimental. Some
>   features were implemented based on early proposals, and no attempt
>   will be made to maintain backward compatibility when they are updated
>   to match the final C++11 standard.

By the way, all features of the C++11 standard are realized in GCC, it's actually old standard, since now C++14 is already approved, but support is still expiremental.

I have no idea WHY it's still experimental, for example on clang site:

> Clang fully implements all published ISO C++ standards including
>   C++11, as well as the upcoming C++14 standard, and some parts of the
>   fledgling C++1z standard, and is considered a production-quality C++
>   compiler.

And only C++1z support is experimental.

Comment: Okay so is this *experimental* related to `unordered_map` bad, or is this class fully implemented and I can just use it and be happy?

Comment: @user826955 second. All support of C++11 is still experimental in gcc, but you can use it.

Comment: please see my comments in the original post

Answer (score 0):

You should upgrade to `gcc 4.9.2`, if you can.  Otherwise use `gcc 4.4`.  They'll both need the `-std=c++0x` option.

Comment: Actually, with `4.9.2`, you should be using `-std=c++11`, not `0x`.